# Exporting value from Redux, making it global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using [redux-responsive](https://github.com/AlecAivazis/redux-responsive) as a help tool for creating a responsive design.

I'm getting a boolean prop whether the device has desktop width or not that I'm passing from Redux like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  desktop: state.browser.greaterThan.small,
})
```

This is defined in so many places all over the application that I'd like to skip `mapStateToProps` and export it once and importing it something like this instead:

```
import { desktop } from './someWhereInStore.js';
```

I wonder though how and where to export the `desktop` value in Redux?

Answer (score 1):

In one way or another you will have to connect your component to the store. You could implement a wrapper to factorize your mapping:

```
export function wrapper(WrappedComponent) {

    class WrapperComponent extends Component {

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent
                {...this.props}
                desktop={this.props.desktop}
            />
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        desktop: state.browser.greaterThan.small,
    })

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(WrapperComponent);
}
```

And replace

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  desktop: state.browser.greaterThan.small,
});    

connect(mapStateToProps)(...);
```

by

```
wrapper(...);
```